# How to select range of data in JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Example Of JSON Data

```
"Data": [
{
  "Symbol": "PTT",
  "CandleCollection": [
    {
      "Open": 248.0,
      "High": 250.0,   //1

    },
    {
      "Open": 239.0,
      "High": 241.0,  //2

    },
    {
      "Open": 225.0,
      "High": 229.0,  //3

    },
    {
      "Open": 215.0,
      "High": 216.0, //4

    },
    {
      "Open": 215.0,
      "High": 218.0, //5

    },
```

Example: I need to select first data at  2 and end data at 4

My json input code on c# is:

```
            foreach (JToken data in jsonInputObj["Data"])
            {
                List<CandleStick> candleArray = new List<CandleStick>();

                foreach (JToken candleStick in data["CandleCollection"])
                {
                    double open = candleStick["Open"].ToObject<double>();
                    double high = candleStick["High"].ToObject<double>();

                    candleArray.Add(new CandleStick(open, high);
                }
                CandleCollection candleList = new CandleCollection(candleArray);
                symbolList.Add(data["Symbol"].ToString(), candleList);
            }
```

//
This loop is get data from .json file into List

This is impossible to select data range on this loop?

Comment: can you show me how to loop ? I'm not professional with code programming.

Comment: Is the above loop fetching all the data properly??

Comment: Yes. It fetch all data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the inner-most `foreach` loop with `for` loop and you are good to go. Like:

```
foreach (JToken data in jsonInputObj["Data"])
{
      List<CandleStick> candleArray = new List<CandleStick>();
      var Candles = data["CandleCollection"];
      for (int i = 0; i < Candles.Count(); i++)
      {
          //This will skip the first and last 
          if (i == 0 || i == Candles.Count() - 1) continue;

          JToken candleStick = Candles[i];
          double open = candleStick["Open"].ToObject<double>();
          double high = candleStick["High"].ToObject<double>();

          candleArray.Add(new CandleStick(open, high));
      }

      CandleCollection candleList = new CandleCollection(candleArray);
      symbolList.Add(data["Symbol"].ToString(), candleList);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Updated my answer to fit-in your solution as mine is causing troubles for you. Try this:

```
foreach (JToken data in jsonInputObj["Data"])
{
     List<CandleStick> candleArray = new List<CandleStick>();

     int i = 1;
     int finalCount = data["CandleCollection"].Count();
     foreach (JToken candleStick in data["CandleCollection"])
     {
          if (i == 1 || i == finalCount) continue;
          i += 1;
          double open = candleStick["Open"].ToObject<double>();
          double high = candleStick["High"].ToObject<double>();

          candleArray.Add(new CandleStick(open, high));
     }
     CandleCollection candleList = new CandleCollection(candleArray);
     symbolList.Add(data["Symbol"].ToString(), candleList);
}
```

PS: I believe `Count()` should have worked for you!

Comment: It's said "'JToken' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'JToken' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Try changing `Candles.Length` in `for (int i = 0; i < Candles.Length; i++)` with `Candles.Count()` ie, `for (int i = 0; i < Candles.Count(); i++)`. And in `if (i == 0 || i == Candles.Length - 1) continue;` as `if (i == 0 || i == Candles.Count() - 1) continue;` I've wrote it out of my head without testing. So tweak it wherever possible. Also if this worked, do tell. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I believe `Count()` should have worked. Can you edit the question with my solution and post the line where you are facing error

Comment: Glad it worked! Just out of curiosity, which one worked for u?

Comment: and if i need to change range ( not just skip first and last ). i need to change " if (i == 1 || i == finalCount) continue;
          i += 1;" ?

Comment: If you want to specifically skip something, provide a constant like `if (i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7)`